# Intellij Idea not building when I press Run

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I have a simple hello world project in Kotlin, running in Intellij Idea. I can build and run it just fine, but if I make changes, save and press the green run button (or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>), Intellij runs the old version of the file, before I made the changes. I can fix this by first Building the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>), then running it (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>). Why is this? Must I always build first, then run? Why doesn't Run build the project for me?

Here is my code, though I'm sure that's not the problem:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("hello world")
}
```

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of the run/debug configuration? Do you have the Build action in the Before launch list?

Comment: As I was typing my comment, I saw the above one come in. Follow the procedure above. Click on the plus sign to add Build if it isn't present. This will build your project when you click run

Comment: In case the above isn't clear, go to Run ---> Edit Configurations. There you will find a drop down called Before launch: Build, Activate tool window. There should be Build in the list. If there isn't click on the plus sign and add it and click ok.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Alf, I didn't even notice that dropdown, but that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The configuration DOES have "Build" before launch. Not even deleting target files for the classes in question helps.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the source directory is correctly configured in the project and that your code is actually in the source directory. Sometimes people import projects or there are some nuiances that cause you to have the code but the directory (src/main/kotlin for example) is not setup as a source code folder.

Is it a maven or gradle project? Or something else? Intellij has auto-detection for maven/gradle to setup the project but sometimes it must manually be triggered to do so if there have been changes made after the project was created or there is a pathing issue between intellij and the executables.

What did the "events" tab say or the output of the run screen?

Odds are good that intellij just isn't correctly configured to know about the project. It might be treating it like a generic project instead of a gradle/maven project for example. Or a java project that has no source code directory defined yet.

Goto the File --> Project Structure Settings --> Modules

And make sure that the "Mark As" for "sources" are correct.

Comment: I find that it works when kotlin file is under `main\kotlin`, if rename `kotlin` to other, the kotlin flies are ignored

Answer (score -1):

IntelliJ uses defined libraries as your dependencies to build and run the application.
So it looks into: Project Structure -> Module -> Dependencies

**If IntelliJ cannot run your project, some dependencies are missing there for sure!**

*For you to solve the issue, add the missing jar file or the folder containing the jar files there and the problem will be solved immediately!*